# Remove the word 'Page' from indexed_search pagination?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-9.x, tx-indexed-search

The indexed_search pagination outputs links like "Page 1, Page 2, Page 3"
Is there any way to edit it to remove the word 'Page' so the output is just the numbers?

```
<is:pageBrowsingResults numberOfResults="{result.count}" currentPage="{searchParams.pointer}" resultsPerPage="{searchParams.numberOfResults}" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just looked into the code and saw that the page label is fetched from the locallang with index `displayResults.page`.

With `plugin.tx_indexedsearch._LOCAL_LANG.en.displayResults.page =` and without a string behind the `=` it should work.
The `en` is for the language key, you need to set it for every language.

The documentation you can find here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/TopLevelObjects/Plugin.html#local-lang-lang-key-label-key

Comment: Adding this doesn't seem to do anything?

Comment: Ok, so in my case I needed to use `default`, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From Typo3 10 onwards we have no pagination HTML template, instead Typo3 has provided ViewHelper for PageBrowser.
So, We can extend that viewhelper in our Template provider extension and edit as per our needs.